# Is it possible to add -pedantic to GCC command line, yet have it not warn about 'long long'

Tags: gcc, long-long

I'm using mostly GCC to develop my library, but I'd like to ensure cross-compiler compatibility and especially standard conformance as much as possible.  For this, I have add several `-W...` flags to command line.  I'd also add `-pedantic`, but I have a problem with its warning about `long long` type.  The latter is important for my library and is properly guarded with `#if` code, i.e. is not compiled on compilers that don't know it anyway.

In short: can I have GCC in `-pedantic` mode warn about any extension *except* `long long`?

Comment: You may want to consider including `<stdint.h>` and using C99-style `int64_t` or `uint64_t` instead.

Comment: @Joey Adams: Good idea, I need to look into that, might also eliminate certain complications in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `-Wno-long-long` , or switch to C99 (use the gcc flag -std=c99). c99 provides long long.

Comment: Oh, I feel stupid now.  I knew about disabling specific warnings but for some reason it never occurred to me I could disable warnings from `-pedantic` this way too.  Thanks, that works!